# Ember run loop ignores pauseFor() in testing

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise

I have an acceptance test which breaks into the following error:

```
Assertion failed: You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the run loop's autorun. You will need to wrap any code with asynchronous side-effects in an Ember.run
```

When I wrap up my code in the run function, pauseFor and any mouseEvents are ignored.

```
test('pauseFor does not wait', async function(assert){
  Ember.run(async function () {
  // doing something
  await pauseFor(3000);
  });
});
```

How can I prevent this error from happening?